# .NET or COM HID iCLASS Smart Card Reader

Tags: c#, .net, smartcard, winscard, iso-15693

I have coding I almost always use with my Omnikey RFID CardMan 5321 smart cards.  Problem is we received new cards today which are marked "HID iCLASS GL" which do not appear to be working well with our coding.

Without going through the whole source, our problem is arising when we are calling the following line, which basically tells us the length of the data:
lResult = SCardTransmit(hCard, 0, bytCommand, lLen, 0, byReadBuffer, iReturnlength)

We are returning only a length of 2, which the data is marked as  "x69 x86". Even if I tell it to read all 255 chr's the rest are just marked as null.

Now I know our reader can read these cards since the OMNIKEY Diagnostic tool is showing us the following:
Status: Smart Card Inserted
FW: 5.10
Port: USB
Lib: 1.0
Smart Card Nme: iCLASS 32KS 8x2+16
ART: Valid 
Protocol: ISO 15693 (Part 2)
PICCtoPCD: 26,48 kbps
PCDtoPICC: 26,48 kbps
Frequ: 13.56 MHz

As I explained before, everything is working fine in my coding except no data is being returned for my card besides "x69 x86", which is surely not correct.

If anyone has any experience reading from a HID iCLASS card, I would greatly appreciate some feedback on how to. Even if we have to license software, that is ok.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI,OMNIKEY Diagnostic tool is old tool.you can use HID Omnikey Workbench..It is more advance than OMNIKEY Diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason cause you get a 2 Byte array is cause your command runs on an error so the chip returns only SW1 and SW2 Flag

in your case it's meaning is

```
x69 --> Command not allowed (further qualification in SW2, see table 17) 
x86 --> Command not allowed (no current EF)
```

So you might proof that your application file on the chip is correctly selected
further information @
http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx#table17

Comment: Sorry did not see this till just now, but i ended up solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

in case you are trying to access physical access data, I would thoroughly check the crypto protocol between reader and host first and also meke sure you are using a reader with teh latest firmware (5.20 for the OMNIKEY 5321).

I would also introduce code to check the card system withour secure communication channel between host and reader application.

Further references: 
http://www.hidglobal.com/documents/ok_contactless_developer_guide_an_en.pdf